# python print to file instead output screen

Tags: python, json, xml

I have the following python script (it 'converts' xml to for example json):

```
import xmltodict
import pprint
import json

with open('file.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(json.dumps(doc))
```

When I run the following code it will output the json code. Question is; how can I write the output to output.json instead of the output to the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @HRR1337 please check my answer below ans see if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

To print Json into file

```
with open("your_output_file.json", "w+") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(doc))
```

To read JSON from file

```
with open("your_output_file.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

To format json with indents you can use indent argument ([link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)).

```
with open('file.xml', 'r') as src_file, open('file.json', 'w+') as dst_file:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(src_file.read()) #read file
    dst_file.write(json.dumps(doc, indent=4)) #write file
```

Comment: Why not use `json.dump()` to directly write to the file?

Comment: @quamrana, I don't think that there's any difference between `file.write(json.dumps(data))` and `json.dumps(data, file)`. First variant is just more "obvious" for me.

Answer (score 0):

To write your dictionary `dct` to a file, use [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

```
with open("output.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(dct,f)
```

To read your dictionary from a file, use [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

```
with open("output.json", "w+") as f:
    dct = json.load(f)
```

Combining both examples

```
In [8]: import json                                                                                                                                                               

In [9]: dct = {'a':'b','c':'d'}                                                                                                                                                   

In [10]: with open("output.json", "w") as f: 
    ...:     json.dump(dct,f) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [11]: with open("output.json", "r") as f: 
    ...:     print(json.load(f)) 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                          
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```